# Close a duplicate question with a question of no upvoted or accepted answers

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Consider [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44701/is-there-a-permanent-hell) question. I want to close it as a duplicate to [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32293/what-is-the-scriptural-basis-for-eternal-hell-as-madhvas-believes) question.

I wanted to close the first question as duplicate to the second one. But it is showing that

> This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer

Does it mean, I cannot close the question with another question of zero answers?

Comment: Seems like that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844

Comment: You should flag mods for such questions